# remove file path and extension in Tcl command

Tags: tcl

say the file path is saved as an variable f

```
puts "$f"
```

Then outcome is

```
/home/usr/testfile.txt
```

I want to remove everything but the name, 'testfile' and save it in a new variable.

Answer (score 19):

The [file](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm) command is what you want.

```
 set fbasename [file rootname [file tail $f]]
```

file tail is the last component of the filename.
file rootname is everything excepting the extension.

Comment: Hi, is there a fast way of doing the same thing in shell script? Instead of using 'cut' command?